# Joomla 3.4 external login php script gives Fatal error ClassLoader.php

Tags: php, joomla, authentication, classloader, fatal-error

SO the above code posted has worked great until Joomla 3.3 upgraded to 3.4 and now my code is producing this

Error I get:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function Composer\Autoload\includeFile() in /home4/chiefres/public_html/cms/libraries/ClassLoader.php on line 43

Code producing error below - any ideas on what is going on? I tried a full install (this was an upgrade from 3.3 originally) and that didn't help either. Cleared caches etc no help.  Thanks.

this code is located in the root of the site and joomla is in the cms subdirectory.

============

```
<?php
/**
* @package Joomla.Site
*
* @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
* @license GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
*/

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.1', '<'))
{
die('Your host needs to use PHP 5.3.1 or higher to run this version of Joomla!');
}

/**
* Constant that is checked in included files to prevent direct access.
* define() is used in the installation folder rather than "const" to not error for PHP 5.2 and lower

define('_JEXEC', 1);

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/cms/defines.php'))
{
include_once __DIR__ . '/cms/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
//define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
define('JPATH_BASE', "./cms");
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// Mark afterLoad in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterLoad') : null;

// Instantiate the application.
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

// Initialise the application.
$app->initialise();

//echo($username);
//echo($password);
$credentials = array( 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
$options=array( 'remember' => boolean );
$login_site =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$login_site->login($credentials, $options);

// $app->redirect("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); // you can redirect anywhere

?>
```

found that the problem was I was trying to login to phpbb and joomla in the same script. Worked until 3.4 joomla. Apparently phpbb common.php has something that causes the fatal classloader.php error. Removing the phpbb include for common.php solved the error.

Still having trouble completing login to joomla this code snip doesn't work anymore

```
$credentials = array( 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
 $options=array( 'remember' => 'boolean' );
 $login_site =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
 $login_site->initialise();
 $login_site->login($credentials, $options);
```

and instead now gives:
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /cms/libraries/joomla/user/helper.php on line 341

Can someone post an example of working external login code for 3.4

Comment: I would suggest reporting this issue to the Joomla-CMS repository on Github